# Is it OK if I flag a question for removal because the OP is being rude to everyone trying to answer his question?

Tags: discussion, questions

Today I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183519/string-constant-pool-new-object-initialization-with-new-keyword-versus-normal) question. Whenever we are asking for *clarification* or *telling the OP (politely) that his understanding is wrong*, the OP is making a *mockery* of our politeness. He is passing useless comments about people whom I have known for quite some time now (I know that they are really smart.).

The question is not well framed, so, it cannot have a proper answer (So, I voted to close it). Shouldn't it be better to remove that question considering the fact that it makes no sense . There are some answers (one answer is really detailed), but an answer to an improper question is almost always ignored (Will you read an answer if you don't understand the question?).

Should I flag it for removal (keeping in mind that the OP is being rude..) ?

Comment: Simply downvote and closevote, they will be question banned soon enough (and probably create a new account). You could otherwise use a custom flag asking for a suspension, but that would probably have the same effect (the user creating a new account) and only lead to more work for the mods.

Comment: If you flag a moderator then he'll just delete all the comments.  If you want the question deleted then it has to be closed first.  Well, that's what happened.

Comment: @l4mpi - I down-voted and *voted to close*. Didn't raise a flag for deletion as I was not sure whether it would be appropriate

Comment: @HansPassant - Yep. Its deleted now

Comment: Why was the question deleted? I am not a mod (not enough rep) and there is no discussion here as to why. It might be relevant to this question to see the thought process as to why that question was ultimately deleted.

Comment: I was hoping to see the question too but only for entertainment.

Comment: @trysis 3 users voted to delete the question, it was not deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense I guess. I suppose that means there isn't any specific reason why it was deleted, just a couple people who didn't like the asker (or read this question and agreed with TheLostMind).

Comment: @billynoah - The question went from *rude to funny* :P

Comment: @trysis - Not exactly.. The question was deleted because it was making very little sense.. And the OP was being rude when we were asking for clarification

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that from this question, but now reading it again it makes sense. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Btw, "Are you saying that concat changes the immutable string s1" is a bad thing to say - it seems to get cause and effect backwards and therefore is more difficult to understand. It's immutable because nothing changes the object - it's not that nothing changes it because it's immutable!

Comment: I still don't understand what they were trying to ask, even after reading all of it. : (

Comment: I see stubbornness (and misguided ideas about how Java works) from OP and impatience on the part of several commentators with OP's stubbornness. However, the only rudeness I see (an _ad hominem_ comment) was from JB Nizet ("you seem be convinced that you know better than everyone out here. Then why are you asking?"). Can you point out where OP being rude?

Comment: @TedHopp - Some comments have been removed after I flagged them.. They were (literally) like - *.. don't answer if you don't know anything about it..* .This isn't how you speak to anyone (smart or dumb). The OP should show some respect

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the removed comments. Those do sound pretty bad (and perhaps explains JB Nizet's comment).

Comment: I would say only if it is ok to flag or delete RESPONSES that are rude, snarky, and totally unhelpful. That happens all the time.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

- Is the question off-topic for whatever reason? Then flag/vote it as off-topic with the appropriate reason.
- Is somebody, anybody, being unreasonable in comments? Flag the comment(s) with the appropriate reason.

That's really all that needs to be done. You do not need to do anything with the question because something is happening in the comments or vice versa. If the OP is being an (expletive) in the comments but the question is otherwise fine, flag the comments only. If the question is incomprehensible regardless of comments, vote on it appropriately.

Comment: flag just the comments or the question / answer itself?.

Comment: Again: if you have beef with a comment, flag the comment. If you have an issue with the question or answer, flag the question or answer. If you have an issue with both *independently*, flag both independently. You need to objectively evaluate each thing on its own. The question doesn't get any better or worse because of comments which may be underneath it.

Comment: If it's just not a single comment, or a handful, but a bigger pattern, an "other"-flag might be appropriate. But then get into the details!

Comment: Yes. Deleting his question is not a legitimate punishment. We might kill the user entirely but not the question if that is valid on its own.

Comment: @TheLostMind Note that it may sometimes be more efficient to flag a question (but not for removal!) where there is a protracted non-constructive argument. Flagging every single comment means that a mod will have to look at and judge each comment separately (possibly in isolation, if the moderator UI hasn't improved). It's sometimes easier on everyone to flag the question or answer with a custom flag and just say "Rude argument in comments between X and Y adds no value to the post" or similar. Note that this is *very different* from flagging for the question or answer to *removed*, of course!

Comment: @apsillers As far as I remember having been told / shown, moderators see all comments flagged on a single post at a time when reviewing comments. Flagging individual comments saves moderators from having to review all comments on a post and determining which should be removed themselves (in addition to possibly having to navigate around because they can't delete comments from the post-reviewing UI AFAIR ... vaguely), but it is indeed appropriate to flag a post instead of many comments individually.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by deceze is excellent and should be taken as a canonical, generic answer to situations like this.  However, I intend to answer on a more specific point about this particular answer.

At best, it's a duplicate of "[What is the difference between "text" and new String("text")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext)".  Regardless of the OP's demeanor towards others, I would have voted to close as a duplicate on it.

As the advice says, one needs to look at the content objectively and independently from one another.  If the OP makes clarifying remarks about the question, that's a good thing; they can be edited into the question.  If they make inflammatory remarks, flag the remarks; they add nothing to the question and may be mass pruned if flagged *anyway*.

In particular, there was nothing really *wrong* with the question (it could've used a bit of wordsmithing to come across clearer), so the closure as "unclear" was unwarranted.

Comment: *Regardless of the OP's demeanor towards others* - I kind of disagree. The attitude of the OP matters. If you check the question, we stopped responding to the OP's *reckless* comments. The OP says - *There are now 3 objects in string pool ("abc", "def", and "abcdef"),* which is incorrect. The question itself is flawed and the OP doesn't want to change it (*don't answer if you don't know... Go read some basics*). What could be possibly obtained from this question?

Comment: Suppose the comments were deleted.  Who cares about 'em?  Does the question read OK without the comments?