# Keep linked questions alive

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

I came across this post: [Is it OK if I flag a question for removal because the OP is being rude to everyone trying to answer his question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294063/is-it-ok-if-i-flag-a-question-for-removal-because-the-op-is-being-rude-to-everyo?cb=1) a few minutes ago and I was genuinely interested in what the linked question looked like, however it has been deleted.

It would be wonderful to keep a living copy, for some amount of time, when a question is linked and is deleted.  The post feels like it has no frame of reference now for future readers.

Comment: Better to ask [for an image of it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1XcbS.jpg)

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the case of your particular question, one doesn't actually need to look at the referenced content to answer it.  I don't need to look at your example question to tell you that a question should not be deleted just because the author is making rude comments.  Now if the question was asking why it was deleted (yours is not), then I'd probably need to look at the post.

In the (relatively rare) cases where some deleted content is highly relevant to a particular meta post, and the issue surrounding that meta post has not yet been resolved, then a mod or 10k user can quote/screenshot the relevant content into the meta post.

Having said that, I've found that in the vast majority of meta discussions about a particular issue discussing deleted content, one does not need to look at the deleted content to answer the question.  Given that there are reasonable enough workaround for the exceptional cases where it *is* needed, there's no need for a feature.

Comment: I suppose it is opinion based.  I can understand what you are saying, and it does depend on the question and I wasn't aware of the mod/10k user ability, which seems like it would be more than sufficient, thank you!